# Can't open React Native project

Tags: react-native, github, npm

I have a problem with RN. I'm a newbie in RN, but I know a little bit of React.

So I tried to clone and open this project: https://github.com/mapbox/store-locator-react-native/

But I couldn't. I tried putting expo and running the project on an Android emulator, but even after I tried installing and uninstalling multiple packages, I always get some error. I also tried with npx react-native run-android but it doesn't work (in the folder with the project, not the base).

Could please someone tell me how to make this project work on my local machine and maybe even upgrade it to the newest RN?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have to navigate to your project

follow the steps 
i am assuming your project on Desktop
launch terminal  and write

```
cd Desktop/RNStoreLocatorExample
```

if you have IOS platform
do

```
npm install

cd ios
```

then

```
pod init 
pod install 

cd ..

react-native run-ios
```

or if you have android 
write

```
 react-native run-android
```

**Hope it will work**

Comment: Hi, I tried this for android and I get this error: 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Pitis\Documents\store-locator-react-native\RNStoreLocatorExample\node_modules\react-native-linear-gradient\android\build.gradle' line: 21

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-linear-gradient'.
> Could not find method compileOnly() for arguments [com.facebook.react:react-native:+] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Comment: @Pitis can you please make a new project on desk top like launch terminal navigate to Desktop with cd Desktop and write react-native init store-locator-react-native  and then cd store-locator-react-native then npm install  and then run on android will work